# Dropdown list disable / enable based on loading completed or not

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to disable a dropdown list when loading therefore the user can not click an item. After it completed loading then enable it. There is a property [disable](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/DropDownListComponent/) so I bind it with a boolean value.

The code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <div class="example-wrapper">
      <p>T-shirt size:</p>
      <kendo-dropdownlist 
        [data]="listItems"
        disable="loading">
     </kendo-dropdownlist>
   </div>
 })
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    public loading: boolean;
    public listItems: Array<string>;
    ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.listItems = ["X-Small", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "X-Large", "2X-Large"];
    setTimeout(function(){ this.loading = false; }, 5000);
  }
}
```

But it is not working which means even I changed the boolean value there is no impaction on it.

Please see [**Stackblize Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqytq7)

My question:

How to make it work? If not, any alternative way to add a spinning overlay it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `disabled` property to your model using square bracket notation. And you have misspelled the `disabled` attribute as `disable`.

```
[disabled]="loading"
```

Also, you have used a `function() { }` for your callback, which means that `this` is scoped to the function itself. You need to use an arrow function to update the component property.

```html
<kendo-dropdownlist [data]="listItems" [disabled]="loading">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqytq7-dwnirt

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it using the below snippet:

```
[disabled]="loading"
```

Example:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: `
  <div class="example-wrapper">
  <p>T-shirt size:</p>
  <kendo-dropdownlist 
    data]="listItems"
    [disabled]="loading">
  </kendo-dropdownlist>
  </div>
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
 public loading: boolean;
 public listItems: Array<string>;
 ngOnInit() {
 this.loading = true;
 this.listItems = ["X-Small", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "X-Large", "2X-Large"];
 setTimeout(()=>{ this.loading = false; }, 5000);
 }
}
```